# typedef int& A can't be used as const A a = 1;

Tags: c++, c++17

why can't it declare as

```
typedef int& A;
const A a = 3;
```

which throws
`cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'A' {aka 'int&'} to an rvalue of type 'int'`

Does it have any difference between
`const int& a = 3;`

Answer (score 4):

> Does it have any difference between `const int& a = 3;`

Yes. Given `const A`, `const` is qualified on `A` itself; `A` is a reference as `int &`, and the reference itself can't be const-qualified, the `const` qualifier is just ignored. As the effect, `const A` is same as `int&` (but not `const int&`), and `int& a = 3;` is ill-formed as the error message said.

Comment: Oh I do not quite understand it in c++ draft,  that's helps a lot. thanks!